# Python tkinter "Select All" checkbox and alignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want a select all check box on top of all check boxes by selecting that all check boxes should be selected. After clicking on the NEXT button the second frame will appear with the checkboxes mentioned in the list in the code.

```
from tkinter import *
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)

def Quit():
    root.destroy()
checkvar1 = IntVar()  
  
checkvar2 = IntVar()  
  
checkvar3 = IntVar()

def checkbox():
    raise_frame(f2)
    IPR_List=["COMM 662 SCTP PATH UP","COMM 665 SCTP PATH DOWN","COMM 478 GLOBALMTITLE TRANSLATION      FAILURE","COMM 275 MTP LEVEL ROUTING ERROR",
              "COMM 628 SCTP ASSOCIATION ESTABLISHED","COMM 0629 SCTP ASSOCIATION TERMINATED","COMM 137 CCS7:SRC DPC FAILED","139 CCS7:SRC DPC ACTIVATED",
              "COMM 338 CCS7:SCCP SUBSYS--OUT-OF-SERVICE","COMM 339 CCS7:SCCP SUBSYS--IN-OF-SERVICE","363 SCCP:ROUTE on PC/SSN FAILURE",
              "COMM 479 FLEX RTNG FILTERING MATCHED","COMM 271 GATEWAY.SS7 MSU REJECTED","COMM 93 CCS7:SEQ TABLE CKSUM MISMATCH",]
    j=0
    for i in IPR_List:
        chkbtn = Checkbutton(f2, text = i,  onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 2, width = 70).grid(row=j,column=1)
        j=j+1
    
for frame in (f1, f2):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')


sd=StringVar()
pathlabel = Entry(f1,text=sd,font=('times',10,'bold'),fg='blue',bg='white',width=60)
pathlabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
browsebutton = Button(f1, text="Browse")
browsebutton.grid(row=1,column=2)
Button(f1, text='NEXT', command=checkbox).grid(row=2,column=1)

Quit = Button(f1, text="Quit", command=Quit)
Quit.grid(row=2,column=2)




raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to keep all my checkboxes to the left in one line .on top of that I want a select all check box on top of all check boxes by selecting that all check boxes should be selected.

Comment: For alignment, add `anchor="w"` to `Checkbutton(...)`.

Comment: Add a #python tag, it may help to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution (it probably can be simplified but... a solution it is):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, Frame, IntVar


class Options:
    def __init__(self, parent, name, selection=None, select_all=False):
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name
        self.selection = selection

        self.variable = IntVar()
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self.parent, text=self.name,
                                       variable=self.variable, command=self.check)

        if selection is None:
            self.checkbutton.pack(side='top')
        elif select_all:
            self.checkbutton.config(command=self.select_all)
            self.checkbutton.pack()
            for item in self.selection:
                item.checkbutton.pack(side='top')

    def check(self):
        state = self.variable.get()
        if state == 1:
            print(f'Selected: {self.name}')

            if all([True if item.variable.get() == 1 else False for item in self.selection[:-1]]):
                self.selection[-1].checkbutton.select()

        elif state == 0:
            print(f'Deselected: {self.name}')

            if self.selection[-1].variable.get() == 1:
                self.selection[-1].checkbutton.deselect()

    def select_all(self):
        state = self.variable.get()
        if state == 1:
            for item in self.selection[:-1]:
                item.checkbutton.deselect()
                item.checkbutton.invoke()
        elif state == 0:
            for item in self.selection[:-1]:
                item.checkbutton.select()
                item.checkbutton.invoke()


selection = []

root = Tk()

option_frame = Frame(root)
option_frame.pack(side='left', fill='y')

for i in range(5):
    selection.append(Options(option_frame, f'Option {i + 1}', selection))
selection.append(Options(option_frame, 'Select All', selection, True))

root.mainloop()
```

A quick explanation about how this should be set up. If You have a group of checkboxes that You want to add a `select all` checkbox You have to append them all to a list and put that list as third argument when creating them in a loop like in the example. Then after the loop You want to append another instance but You have to also set the fourth argument to True. That will allow to easily create checkboxes with a select all. If You just want to have a few checkboxes just put them in a loop and add only the first two arguments: parent and name.

Hope that clears up how to set up. About coding part:

Some confusion may arise when in the code it deselects all and then invokes when it should select. The reason is that first all checkboxes need to be cleared because `.invoke()` toggles them to the opposite and also simulates user input so all the checkboxes will call `.check()` method, and for deselection it works the opposite way.

```py
def select_all(self):
    state = self.variable.get()
    if state == 1:
        for item in self.selection[:-1]:
            item.checkbutton.deselect()
            item.checkbutton.invoke()
    elif state == 0:
        for item in self.selection[:-1]:
            item.checkbutton.select()
            item.checkbutton.invoke()
```

Also the code could be made less complex if the function of if all are selected and one or more get deselected by the user also deselect automatically the select all checkbox because it is untrue. (last 2 lines)

```py
elif state == 0:
    print(f'Deselected: {self.name}')

    if self.selection[-1].variable.get() == 1:
        self.selection[-1].checkbutton.deselect()
```

EDIT 1: added code that selects select_all checkbox if all checboxes are selected by user (and select_all hasn't been selected by the user) (last 2 lines)

```py
if state == 1:
    print(f'Selected: {self.name}')

    if all([True if item.variable.get() == 1 else False for item in self.selection[:-1]]):
        self.selection[-1].checkbutton.select()
```

I would say the rest is pretty simple python logic, so if You have questions, ask them.

> Here is the source I used for [Checkbox](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm) attributes and methods.

Comment: See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (because I just had a need to flag a question as a duplicate and provide this as an already answered question which I couldn't because it wasn't accepted, so if this answers your question, please mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 0):

```
   for i in range(len(IPR_LIST)):  
        Checkbutton(root2,text=IPR_LIST[i],variable=chkboxlist[i]).place(relx=x,rely=y)
        y=y+0.05
        c=c+1
        if c==8:
            x=x+0.15
            y=0.05
            c=0
```